# Spring boot downloads jsp file, not renders

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple spring-boot application and I have a problem. Instead of rendering a jsp page, it is downloaded. I have seen some Stack Overflow questions about this but none of them was useful.

Folder structure looks like this:

[image]

This is `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8089
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testing
spring.datasource.platform=oracle
spring.datasource.username=ANONYMOUS
spring.datasource.password=alex
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

This is `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and I run this app with this command:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Last lines in VS Code terminal looks like this:

[image]

What can be problem?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: @JBNizet, I should use `war`, right?

Comment: Yes, since that's what the official documentation says.